# How do I ignore resource creation if already present in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

while configuring resource configuration , is there any way I can use so that serverless wont create throw any error if resource is already present.

eg. don't throw this error if following resource is already present.

Error :  `An error occurred: PaymentQueue - dev_payment_cron_queue already exists in stack`

```
resources:
  Resources:
    PaymentQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:provider.stage}_payment_cron_queue
        VisibilityTimeout: 40
```

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, there is no such way with pure CloudFormation (CFN), as this is not how CFN (or Terraform as a matter of fact) was designed to work. From CFN perspective, a given resource exists and is managed by CFN, or it does not exist at all. There is no middle ground.

If your resource already exist, you have to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) it to CFN so that it gets managed by CFN. Alternatively, you have to create [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in the form of a lambda function. The function would perform any action you want based on the existing resources, including checking if it exists or not.